# Arch Linux installation failed grub installation

Tags: installation, grub, arch-linux

I'm trying to install Arch Linux (LVM, encryption) and I'm stuck on the last step of the installation, and that's the grub configuration.

As soon as I type in `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`, the command has no output and the command execution never ends (I can force stop the command and type others afterwards). `grub-install` worked without errors, and the partitions have the right types.

Basic installation without LVM and encryption works. Mounting grub on `mnt/sda1` (the boot partition) doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by a buggy interaction between the arch-install-scripts and lvm, which is "probably" the fault of lvm for receiving an update that does silly things.

More details can be found on this bug report: https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/61040

The simple workaround is I guess to:

- mount `/run/lvm` into the chroot manually rather than wait for the proposed arch-install-scripts change or a change in lvm itself, or,
- just write your own very simple grub.cfg rather than relying on on the inaccurate detection scripts: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/User:Eschwartz/Grub#Example